# Android - How would a content observer work with an IntentService?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

In the docs, it says that IntentServices are used for asynchronous tasks, which is essentially what I need - however, it also says that the service kills itself when it runs out of work, but I'd like the service to be watching certain values using ContentObservers. Will it kill itself even if its watching these values? Could I use START_STICKY to get it to stay alive until I actually want it dead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Service running all the time, then you don't want to use `IntentService`. Just create your own `Service` and make sure you return `START_STICKY` and stop the `Service` yourself when you are done with it.

There isn't any benefit to using `IntentService` if it doesn't meet your requirements.